# Undefined variables within header files

Tags: c++, header

Thanks for taking the time to view my question. I've spent a lot of time looking but can't find a solution to this problem:

I have a class Person with its' respective Header file Person.h. The cpp class is having a hard time understanding what the variables name, age, and iq are.

```
//Person.cpp

/*
Makes a person.
A person has a name, an age, and an IQ level.
We will create many of these objects within other classes.
*/

#include "Person.h"

Person::Person() //Empty constructor
{

}
Person::Person(string thename, int theage, int theiq)
{
    name = thename;
    age = theage;
    iq = theiq;
}

string getName()
{
    return name; //Error: identifier "name" is undefined
}

int getAge()
{
    return age; //Error: identifier "age" is undefined
}

int getIq()
{
    return iq; //Error: identifier "iq" is undefined
}

void setName(string aName)
{
    name = aName; //Error: identifier "name" is undefined
}

void setAge(int aAge)
{
    age = aAge; //Error: identifier "age" is undefined
}

void setIq(int aIq)
{
    iq = aIq; //Error: identifier "iq" is undefined
}
```

The Header File

```
//=================================
// include guard
#ifndef __PERSON_H_INCLUDED__
#define __PERSON_H_INCLUDED__

//=================================
// forward declared dependencies


//=================================
// included dependencies
#include <string> //For the name


//=================================

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(); //Default constructor
    Person(string thename, int theage, int theiq); //Constructor
    string getName();
    int getAge();
    int getIq();
    void setName(int aName);
    void setAge(int aAge);
    void setIq(int aIq);

private:
    string name;
    int age, iq;
};

#endif //__PERSON_H_
```

**SURELY** I don't have to define the variables inside Person.cpp right? It already knows exactly what variables name, age, and iq are because it saw the header file already. Why can it not understand what those variables are?

If I do, or if there is anything I'm missing, make sure to really spell it out for me. I'm barely an intermediate C++ programmer so I may not understand jargon. Even things like scope, inheritance, and definitions go way over my head.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You forgot to put the function definitions in class scope `Person::` as you did correctly with the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To which ever part you're getting errors do this:
***return type* Person::*function name(parameters)***

For the declaration part of the functions.

For example for the **getAge** function do this:

```
int Person::getAge() {
      return age;
}
```

The reason you got errors is because of the following:

1. First your intention was to define the functions you declared in the **Person** class.
2. In the return statement you wanted to return **age** member of the **Person** class. But you simply returned age.
3. The search for **age** begins inside the function body first. If its not found it is searched in the outer scope. If its still not found **age** is an unknown identifier.

After you fix it what happens is this:

1. The **Person::** part in the ***return type* Person::*function name(parameters)*** means that look in the scope of the Person class.
2. Then in the return statement we return **age** member of the **Person** class. But this time we're looking inside the scope of the **Person** class, hence we return the **age** member and the error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
string getName()
```

to

```
string Person::getName()
```

in the .cpp file. Ditto for the others., The compiler needs to know that this is a part of the class Person.

Comment: Why? Is this because they are private? What does adding the CLASSNAME:: even do? Do I need to do that in both the CPP file and the .H file?

Comment: Do I also need to define variables like: Person::int name ? If not, why?

Comment: Perhaps review your C++ book. You got it correct with the constructors Just need to do it with the other methods

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
string getName()
{
return name; //Error: identifier "name" is undefined
}
```

is not defining the class member function. Instead you are declaring and defining a (completely different and unrelated) free function. As such, `name` is undefined within the scope of this function.